Validation in my cigarettebrand.jsx is not working correctly
On page load of my CigaretteBrand page, --None Selected-- is the default initial values in my required dropdowns. When I click continue without changing one of my required dropdown options to a valid selection, it is not displaying my validation message. It only displays my validation message after I click the reset button. I have tried using e.preventDefault in my handleSubmit function but that did not solve my issue either.
Here CigaretteBrand.jsx code:
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import DirectCustomerHelper from "../../js/Helpers/DirectCustomer_helper";
import DropdownHelper from "../../js/Helpers/Dropdown_helper";

const CigaretteBrand = () => {
  const getLastMonthDateRange = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const firstDayLastMonth = new Date(
      now.getFullYear(),
      now.getMonth() - 1,
      1
    );
    const lastDayLastMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 0);

    const formatDate = (date) => date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
    return {
      fromDate: formatDate(firstDayLastMonth),
      toDate: formatDate(lastDayLastMonth),
    };
  };

  const { fromDate, toDate } = getLastMonthDateRange();

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    Warehouse: [],
    Chain: [],
    Location: [],
    LocationGrouping: [],
    SalesAssociate: [],
    Manufacturer: [],
    CigaretteBrand: [],
    FromDate: fromDate,
    ToDate: toDate,
    Include: ["M", "B"],
    ReportType: "Locations",
    BreakByRep: false,
    DirectCustomer: "",
  });

  const [showValidationError, setShowValidationError] = useState(false);

  const formRefs = {
    Warehouse: useRef(null),
    Chain: useRef(null),
    Location: useRef(null),
    SalesAssociate: useRef(null),
    DirectCustomer: useRef(null),
  };

  const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setFormState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
    clearValidationMessage();
  };

  const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    setFormState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: checked,
    }));
    clearValidationMessage();
  };

  const handleMultiSelectChange = (name, options) => {
    const values = options ? options.map((option) => option.value) : [];
    handleChange(name, values);
  };

  const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    handleChange(name, value);
  };

  const isValidSelection = (selection) => {
    return (
      Array.isArray(selection) &&
      selection.length > 0 &&
      selection.some(
        (option) => option !== "" && option !== "-- None Selected --"
      )
    );
  };

  const validateForm = () => {
    const isValid = [
      isValidSelection(formState.Warehouse),
      isValidSelection(formState.Chain),
      isValidSelection(formState.Location),
      isValidSelection(formState.SalesAssociate),
    ].some((val) => val);

    setShowValidationError(!isValid);

    ["Warehouse", "Chain", "Location", "SalesAssociate"].forEach((field) => {
      const fieldRef = formRefs[field].current;
      if (fieldRef) {
        if (!isValidSelection(formState[field])) {
          fieldRef.classList.add("is-invalid");
        } else {
          fieldRef.classList.remove("is-invalid");
        }
      }
    });

    return isValid;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validateForm()) {
      setShowValidationError(false);
      console.log(formState);
      // Your form submission logic here
    } else {
      setShowValidationError(true);
    }
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    const { fromDate, toDate } = getLastMonthDateRange();
    setFormState({
      Warehouse: [],
      Chain: [],
      Location: [],
      LocationGrouping: [],
      SalesAssociate: [],
      Manufacturer: [],
      CigaretteBrand: [],
      FromDate: fromDate,
      ToDate: toDate,
      Include: ["M", "B"],
      ReportType: "Locations",
      BreakByRep: false,
      DirectCustomer: "",
    });
    setShowValidationError(false);
    Object.keys(formRefs).forEach((field) => {
      const fieldRef = formRefs[field].current;
      if (fieldRef) {
        fieldRef.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      }
    });
  };

  const clearValidationMessage = () => {
    setShowValidationError(false);
    ["Warehouse", "Chain", "Location", "SalesAssociate"].forEach((field) => {
      const fieldRef = formRefs[field].current;
      if (fieldRef) {
        fieldRef.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="portlet-body form">
      {showValidationError && (
        <div id="form-validation-error" className="alert alert-danger mx-3">
          You must select at least ONE selection from the following: Warehouse,
          Chain, Location, or Sales Associate.
        </div>
      )}
      <form
        id="CigaretteBrand"
        className="needs-validation"
        noValidate
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <div className="form-body" id="brand-form-body">
          <div className="form-wrapper row">
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-8">
              <div className="form-column">
                <div
                  className="form-group hth-group"
                  ref={formRefs.DirectCustomer}
                >
                  <DirectCustomerHelper
                    initialCustomer={formState.DirectCustomer}
                    onChange={(value) => handleChange("DirectCustomer", value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group hth-group" ref={formRefs.Warehouse}>
                  <DropdownHelper
                    dropdownKeys={["Warehouse"]}
                    onDataFetched={(data) =>
                      handleMultiSelectChange("Warehouse", data.Warehouse)
                    }
                  />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                    Please select a warehouse.
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group hth-group" ref={formRefs.Chain}>
                  <DropdownHelper
                    dropdownKeys={["Chain"]}
                    onDataFetched={(data) =>
                      handleMultiSelectChange("Chain", data.Chain)
                    }
                  />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">Please select a chain.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group hth-group" ref={formRefs.Location}>
                  <DropdownHelper
                    dropdownKeys={["Location"]}
                    onDataFetched={(data) =>
                      handleMultiSelectChange("Location", data.Location)
                    }
                  />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                    Please select a location.
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="form-group hth-group"
                  ref={formRefs.SalesAssociate}
                >
                  <DropdownHelper
                    dropdownKeys={["SalesAssociate"]}
                    onDataFetched={(data) =>
                      handleMultiSelectChange(
                        "SalesAssociate",
                        data.SalesAssociate
                      )
                    }
                  />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                    Please select a sales associate.
                  </div>
                  <label className="normal" htmlFor="BreakByRep">
                    <input
                      className="hth_default"
                      type="checkbox"
                      id="BreakByRep"
                      name="BreakByRep"
                      checked={formState.BreakByRep}
                      onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    Break By Sales Associate
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-8">
              <div className="form-column">
                <div className="form-group hth-group">
                  <DropdownHelper
                    dropdownKeys={["CigaretteBrand"]}
                    onDataFetched={(data) =>
                      handleMultiSelectChange(
                        "CigaretteBrand",
                        data.CigaretteBrand
                      )
                    }
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-column">
                  <div className="form-group hth-group">
                    <label className="mb-2" htmlFor="FromDate">
                      Date Range
                    </label>
                    <label htmlFor="FromDate">From</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="date"
                      id="FromDate"
                      name="FromDate"
                      value={formState.FromDate}
                      onChange={handleDateChange}
                      required
                    />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                      Please provide a valid date.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group hth-group">
                    <label htmlFor="ToDate">To</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="date"
                      id="ToDate"
                      name="ToDate"
                      value={formState.ToDate}
                      onChange={handleDateChange}
                      required
                    />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                      Please provide a valid date.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
                  <div className="form-group hth-group">
                    <label>Include</label>
                    <label className="normal" htmlFor="manufacturer-checkbox">
                      <input
                        id="manufacturer-checkbox"
                        className="hth_default"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="Include"
                        value="M"
                        checked={formState.Include.includes("M")}
                        onChange={() =>
                          handleChange(
                            "Include",
                            formState.Include.includes("M")
                              ? formState.Include.filter((val) => val !== "M")
                              : [...formState.Include, "M"]
                          )
                        }
                      />
                      Vendor
                    </label>
                    <label className="normal" htmlFor="brand-checkbox">
                      <input
                        id="brand-checkbox"
                        className="hth_default"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="Include"
                        value="B"
                        checked={formState.Include.includes("B")}
                        onChange={() =>
                          handleChange(
                            "Include",
                            formState.Include.includes("B")
                              ? formState.Include.filter((val) => val !== "B")
                              : [...formState.Include, "B"]
                          )
                        }
                      />
                      Cigarette Brand
                    </label>
                    <label id="include-error"></label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group hth-group">
                    <label>Report Type</label>
                    <label className="normal" htmlFor="optionsRadios1">
                      <input
                        className="hth_default"
                        type="radio"
                        name="ReportType"
                        id="optionsRadios1"
                        value="Locations"
                        checked={formState.ReportType === "Locations"}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          handleChange("ReportType", e.target.value)
                        }
                      />
                      Locations
                    </label>
                    <label className="normal" htmlFor="optionsRadios2">
                      <input
                        className="hth_default"
                        type="radio"
                        name="ReportType"
                        id="optionsRadios2"
                        value="Summary"
                        checked={formState.ReportType === "Summary"}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          handleChange("ReportType", e.target.value)
                        }
                      />
                      Summary
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-actions fluid">
          <center>
            <div className="caption">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-success"
                id="defaultActionButton"
              >
                Continue <i className="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn"
                id="defaultResetButton"
                onClick={handleReset}
              >
                Reset
              </button>
            </div>
          </center>
          <br />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CigaretteBrand;

Here is my Dropdown_helper.jsx reusable component code:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./Dropdown_helper.css";

const DropdownHelper = ({ onDataFetched, dropdownKeys }) => {
  const hasFetched = useRef(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dropdownData, setDropdownData] = useState({});
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({});
  const [defaultValues, setDefaultValues] = useState({});

  const formatLabel = (item, type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "Warehouse":
        return `${item.WarehouseNumber} ${item.WarehouseName}`;
      case "Location":
        return `${item.LocationName} (${item.CustomerNumber}-${item.LocationNumber})`;
      case "Chain":
        return `${item.ChainNumber} ${item.ChainName}`;
      case "SalesAssociate":
        return `${item.SalesName} (${item.WarehouseNumber}-${item.SalesId})`;
      case "FoodServiceRep":
        return `${item.NAME} (${item.WHSNO}-${item.REP})`;
      case "CigaretteBrand":
        return item.Code;
      case "Vendor":
        return `${item.Code} ${item.Name}`;
      case "LocationGrouping":
        return item.GroupingName;
      default:
        return "";
    }
  };

  const sortAlphabeticallyByLabel = (a, b) => {
    if (a.label < b.label) return -1;
    if (a.label > b.label) return 1;
    return 0;
  };

  const convertLocationGroupingNames = (groupings) => {
    const map = {
      "A STORES": "FS A STORE",
      "B STORES": "FS B STORE",
      "C STORES": "FS C STORE",
      "D STORES": "FS D STORE",
      "E STORES": "FS E STORE",
      "F STORES": "FS F STORE",
      "G STORES": "FS G STORE",
      "H STORES": "FS H STORE",
      "FS EQUIP A FULL KITCHEN W/HOOD": "FS EQUIP A",
      "FS EQUIP B SMALL KITCHEN NO HOOD": "FS EQUIP B",
      "FS EQUIP C NO KITCHEN - COUNTER SPACE ONLY": "FS EQUIP C",
      "FS EQUIP D NO FOOD NEED": "FS EQUIP D",
    };

    return groupings.map((group) => ({
      ...group,
      GroupingName: map[group.GroupingName] || group.GroupingName,
    }));
  };

  const fetchData = async (url, method = "GET", data = null) => {
    return $.ajax({
      url,
      type: method,
      headers: {
        Authorization: getToken(),
      },
      data,
      contentType: "application/json",
    });
  };

  const fetchDropdownData = async (keysToFetch) => {
    try {
      const dropdownData = {};
      let response = {};
      const keysFetching = [];

      if (
        keysToFetch.includes("Warehouse") ||
        keysToFetch.includes("Chain") ||
        keysToFetch.includes("Location") ||
        keysToFetch.includes("LocationGrouping")
      ) {
        keysFetching.push("Warehouse", "Chain", "Location", "LocationGrouping");
        response = await fetchData(
          "https://api.hthackney.com/1/users/authorizations/customers"
        );
        if (keysToFetch.includes("Warehouse"))
          dropdownData.Warehouse = response.Warehouses || [];
        if (keysToFetch.includes("Chain"))
          dropdownData.Chain = response.Chains || [];
        if (keysToFetch.includes("Location"))
          dropdownData.Location = response.Locations || [];
        if (keysToFetch.includes("LocationGrouping"))
          dropdownData.LocationGrouping = convertLocationGroupingNames(
            response.LocationGroupings || []
          );
      }

      if (keysToFetch.includes("SalesAssociate")) {
        keysFetching.push("SalesAssociate");
        response = await fetchData(
          "https://api.hthackney.com/1/users/authorizations/salesassociates"
        );
        dropdownData.SalesAssociate = response.SalesAssociates || [];
      }

      if (keysToFetch.includes("FoodServiceRep")) {
        keysFetching.push("FoodServiceRep");
        response = await fetchData(
          "https://api.hthackney.com/1/users/authorizations/foodservice"
        );
        dropdownData.FoodServiceRep = response.Reps || [];
      }

      if (keysToFetch.includes("CigaretteBrand")) {
        keysFetching.push("CigaretteBrand");
        response = await fetchData(
          "https://api.hthackney.com/1/itemattributes/cigarettebrand",
          "POST",
          JSON.stringify({ Offset: 0, Limit: 10000 })
        );
        dropdownData.CigaretteBrand = response.Codes || [];
      }

      if (keysToFetch.includes("Vendor")) {
        keysFetching.push("Vendor");
        response = await fetchData(
          "https://api.hthackney.com/1/itemattributes/vendor",
          "POST",
          JSON.stringify({ Offset: 0, Limit: 10000 })
        );
        dropdownData.Vendor = response.Codes || [];
      }

      console.log("Dropdown data fetched successfully", dropdownData);
      console.log("Fetched keys:", keysFetching);

      const formatData = (data, type) => {
        const formattedData = data
          .map((item, index) => ({
            value:
              type === "CigaretteBrand" ? item.Code : item[type + "Number"],
            label: formatLabel(item, type),
            key: `${type}-${index}`,
          }))
          .sort(sortAlphabeticallyByLabel);

        return [
          { value: "", label: "-- None Selected --", key: `${type}-default` },
          ...formattedData,
        ];
      };

      const formattedData = {};
      keysToFetch.forEach((key) => {
        if (dropdownData[key]) {
          formattedData[key] = formatData(dropdownData[key], key);
          sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(formattedData[key]));
        }
      });

      setDropdownData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, ...formattedData }));
      const initialSelectedValues = {};
      keysToFetch.forEach((key) => {
        initialSelectedValues[key] = {
          value: "",
          label: "-- None Selected --",
        };
      });
      setSelectedValues(initialSelectedValues);
      setDefaultValues(initialSelectedValues);
      onDataFetched((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, ...formattedData }));
      setLoading(false);
      hasFetched.current = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching dropdown data", error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const getSelectByDropdowns = () => [
    { value: "", label: "-- None Selected --" },
    { value: "allitems", label: "All Items" },
    { value: "individualitems", label: "Individual Items" },
    { value: "standardcategory", label: "Standard Invoice Category" },
    { value: "majorcategory", label: "Major Product Category" },
    { value: "minorcategory", label: "Product Category" },
    { value: "cigarettebrand", label: "Cigarette Brand" },
    { value: "vendor", label: "Vendor" },
    { value: "standardorderbook", label: "Standard Order Book Header" },
    { value: "itemgrouping", label: "Item Grouping" },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasFetched.current) return;
    console.log("DropdownHelper component rendered");

    const cachedData = {};
    let allDataCached = true;
    const keysToFetch = [];

    dropdownKeys.forEach((key) => {
      if (key === "SelectBy") return;

      const cached = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
      if (cached) {
        cachedData[key] = JSON.parse(cached);
        console.log(`Using cached data for ${key}`);
      } else {
        allDataCached = false;
        keysToFetch.push(key);
      }
    });

    if (allDataCached) {
      console.log("Using all cached data");
      setDropdownData(cachedData);
      const initialSelectedValues = {};
      dropdownKeys.forEach((key) => {
        initialSelectedValues[key] = {
          value: "",
          label: "-- None Selected --",
        };
      });
      setSelectedValues(initialSelectedValues);
      setDefaultValues(initialSelectedValues);
      onDataFetched(cachedData);
      setLoading(false);
      hasFetched.current = true;
    } else {
      console.log("Fetching new data for keys:", keysToFetch);
      fetchDropdownData(keysToFetch);
    }
  }, [dropdownKeys, onDataFetched]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(defaultValues).length > 0) {
      setDropdownData((prevData) => {
        const updatedData = { ...prevData };
        Object.keys(defaultValues).forEach((key) => {
          if (
            updatedData[key] &&
            !updatedData[key].some((option) => option.value === "")
          ) {
            updatedData[key] = [defaultValues[key], ...updatedData[key]];
          }
        });
        return updatedData;
      });
    }
  }, [defaultValues]);

  const handleSelectionChange = (key, selected) => {
    const newValue = selected
      ? selected
      : { value: "", label: "-- None Selected --" };
    setSelectedValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [key]: newValue,
    }));
    onDataFetched((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [key]: newValue
        ? [newValue]
        : [{ value: "", label: "-- None Selected --" }],
    }));
  };

  const customStyles = {
    control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      minWidth: "300px",
      width: "100%",
      border: "1px solid #ced4da",
      borderRadius: ".25rem",
      boxShadow: state.isFocused ? "hsl(0, 0%, 70%)" : provided.boxShadow,
      "&:hover": {
        borderColor: "hsl(0, 0%, 70%)",
        cursor: "pointer",
      },
    }),
    menu: (provided) => ({
      ...provided,
      zIndex: 9999,
      transition: "opacity 0.3s ease",
      opacity: 0,
      animation: "fadeIn 0.3s forwards",
    }),
  };

  const readableLabel = (key) => {
    const labels = {
      Warehouse: "Warehouse",
      Location: "Location",
      Chain: "Chain",
      SalesAssociate: "Sales Associate",
      FoodServiceRep: "Food Service Rep",
      CigaretteBrand: "Cigarette Brand",
      Vendor: "Vendor",
      LocationGrouping: "Location Grouping",
      SelectBy: "Select Items By",
    };
    return labels[key] || key;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {dropdownKeys.map((key) => (
        <div className="form-column" key={key}>
          <div className="form-group hth-group">
            <label className="control-label" htmlFor={key}>
              {readableLabel(key)}
            </label>
            <Select
              id={key}
              options={
                key === "SelectBy" ? getSelectByDropdowns() : dropdownData[key]
              }
              styles={customStyles}
              isLoading={loading}
              isDisabled={loading}
              value={
                selectedValues[key] || {
                  value: "",
                  label: "-- None Selected --",
                }
              }
              onChange={(selected) => handleSelectionChange(key, selected)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default DropdownHelper;

I tried using e.preventDefault in my handleSubmit function to prevent the default action of the continue action. That did not resolve my issue.

There's a lot of code here. Any chance of a [mcve] to focus in on the issue?

unfortunately stack overflow wont allow me to edit my question to reduce it down for you. I apologize.
